# The underlying provider failed on Open for some users while performance testing

Tags: entity-framework, azure, gatling

I am testing my application for multiple users through gatling performance tool.When it hits login method for simultaneous users some users logged in successfully but for some users i am getting "The underlying provider failed on Open." error.
Below is the stack trace:

```
at System.Data.EntityClient.EntityConnection.OpenStoreConnectionIf(Boolean openCondition, DbConnection storeConnectionToOpen, DbConnection originalConnection, String exceptionCode, String attemptedOperation, Boolean&amp; closeStoreConnectionOnFailure)
```

at System.Data.EntityClient.EntityConnection.Open()
   at System.Data.Objects.ObjectContext.EnsureConnection()
   at System.Data.Objects.ObjectContext.CreateFunctionObjectResult[TElement](EntityCommand entityCommand, ReadOnlyMetadataCollection`1 entitySets, EdmType[] edmTypes, MergeOption mergeOption)
   at System.Data.Objects.ObjectContext.ExecuteFunction[TElement](String functionName, MergeOption mergeOption, ObjectParameter[] parameters)
   at System.Data.Objects.ObjectContext.ExecuteFunction[TElement](String functionName, ObjectParameter[] parameters)
   at Pals.Entities.PalsEntities.sp_FetchVinStatusForAdminCountModifiedAsn(String dealerid, String oemid, String terminalId, Nullable`1 fromDate, Nullable`1 toDate, String onHoldDisplayFlag)
   at Portal.Business.Implementation.VinStatusCountAdmin.&lt;&gt;c__DisplayClass1.&lt;FetchVinStatusForAdminCountAsn&gt;b__0()
   at Microsoft.Practices.TransientFaultHandling.RetryPolicy.ExecuteAction[TResult](Func`1 func)
   at Portal.Business.Implementation.VinStatusCountAdmin.FetchVinStatusForAdminCountAsn(String dealerId, String oemId, String terminalId, DateTime fromDate, DateTime toDate, String onHoldDisplyaFlag)
   at Portal.Business.Managers.DashBoardManager.GetVinStatusCountForAdmin(String dealerId, String oemId, String terminalId, DateTime fromDate, DateTime toDate, String boardStatus, String onHoldDisplayFlag)
   at Portal.Business.Managers.DashBoardManager.GetDashBoardParallel(SimpleSearch objdao, String boardStatus)
   at Pals.Web.Controllers.SearchController.LoadDashBoardParallel(String dealerId, String shipperId, String terminalId, String fromDate, String toDate, String boardStatus)
   at lambda_method(Closure , ControllerBase , Object[] )
   at System.Web.Mvc.ReflectedActionDescriptor.Execute(ControllerContext controllerContext, IDictionary`2 parameters)
   at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethod(ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor, IDictionary`2 parameters)
   at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.<>c__DisplayClass15.<InvokeActionMethodWithFilters>b__12()
   at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethodFilter(IActionFilter filter, ActionExecutingContext preContext, Func`1 continuation)
   at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethodWithFilters(ControllerContext controllerContext, IList`1 filters, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor, IDictionary`2 parameters)
   at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeAction(ControllerContext controllerContext, String actionName)

I am using entityframework in my application.

Comment: Is there an inner exception?  If so, what is it?

Comment: @BrendanGreen i am getting "The underlying provider failed on Open." in inner exception also.

Comment: Is there an inner inner exception? In every case I've seen and read about, there is *always* a more detailed exception inside.

Comment: @Steve.i just enabled exception detail on error page and through gatling i am getting those responses.I will dig into this at code level and post if got detailed inner exception.

Answer (score 0):

(Assuming you're using EF6)

Have you specified the `SqlAzureExecutionStrategy` in your EF configuration?

If not (or if you don't know what I'm talking about) then you need to create a class in the same project as your `DbContext`) that inherits `DbConfiguration`, and in its constructor, call the `SetExecutionStrategy` protected method, like this:

```
using System.Data.Entity; 
using System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure; 
using System.Data.Entity.SqlServer; 

namespace MyNamespace 
{ 
    public class MyConfiguration : DbConfiguration 
    { 
        public MyConfiguration() 
        { 
            SetExecutionStrategy("System.Data.SqlClient", () => new SqlAzureExecutionStrategy()); 
        } 
    } 
}

// from http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn456835.aspx
```

You can play with the configuration of the `SqlAzureExecutionStrategy` to set things like retry limits, timeouts and so on.

Comment: ..I am using transientfaulthandling for the retry policy and all.